# How to add android auto support for an already existing Flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, android-auto, just-audio, audio-service

I already have a music application built in Flutter. The music uses [`audio_service`](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) and [`just_audio`](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio).

I am currently looking to add an Android Auto support for the music application built using Flutter.

I have been going through the site https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/auto.

But, I am unable to get how to even setup the application for flutter properly. Also, am not able to run the desktop head unit via android emulator.

Leaving these aside, the major thing is how do I start to setup android auto for my application.

For starters, I have checked [this](https://github.com/florent37/Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer/blob/master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/github/florent37/assets_audio_player/AssetsAudioPlayerPlugin.kt) file. Which was posted in the [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26801) of flutter repo. This didn't make much sense as I was not able to even start the setup for android auto process.

Comment: https://github.com/immadisairaj/radiosai is my existing flutter application

Comment: Hey did you find anything

Comment: No, didn’t find any. There seems to be an issue in flutter GitHub. Maybe you can follow it.